# A question on optimal Sobolev inequality. 

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

Let us consider the Sobolev inequality $||u||_{L^p} \le C||u||_{H^1}$ for $2 <p< 2^*$, where the constant $C$ depends on $p$ and the domain. My question is, how can one see that the optimal Sobolev constant is attained at a positive function $f>0$?

By taking the absolute value, it is easy to see that we may take $f\ge 0$. Also when the domain is bounded, we may apply maximal principle. How about when the domain is not bounded?

Comment: Symmetrization and ODE analysis.

Comment: Is it not possible to apply the maximum principle to a sequence of compact domains that exhaust the closure of the original domain?

Comment: Deane Yang: your idea is natural, but doing it in a precise way is a delicate issue when the boundary of the domain is rough.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a variational argument to prove that the maximizers do not change sign.

If $f \in H^1 (\mathbb{R}^N)$ be a maximizer, $u$ can be written as 
$$
  f = f_+ - f_-,
$$
with $f_+ \ne 0$ and $f_- \ne 0$.
Moreover
$$
  \Vert f \Vert_{H^1}^2 =  \Vert f_+ \Vert_{H^1}^2 +  \Vert f_- \Vert_{H^1}^2
$$
and
$$
  \Vert f \Vert_{L^p}^p=  \Vert f_+ \Vert_{L^p}^p +  \Vert f_- \Vert_{L^p}^p.
$$

We have thus
$$
  \Vert f \Vert_{L^p}^2 = \frac{\Vert f_+\Vert_{L^p}^p}{\Vert f\Vert_{L^p}^p} \Vert f\Vert_{L^p}^2 + \frac{\Vert f_-\Vert_{L^p}^p}{\Vert f\Vert_{L^p}^p} \Vert f\Vert_{L^p}^2.
$$
By strict concavity of the map $t \in \mathbb{R} + \mapsto \vert t \vert^{\frac{2}{p}}$ and the optimality of (f),
$$
\Vert f \Vert_{L^p}^2
<\Vert f_+ \Vert_{L^p}^2 + \Vert f_- \Vert_{L^p}^2
\le \frac{\Vert f \Vert_{L^p}^2}{\Vert f \Vert_{H^1}^2}
\bigl(\Vert f_+ \Vert_{H^1}^2 + \Vert f_- \Vert_{H^1}^2 \bigr)
= \Vert f \Vert_{L^p}^p,
$$
which is a contradiction.

Essentially, the argument says that if $f$ changes sign then taking either $f_+$ or $f_-$ increases the quotient.

The argument extends to maximizers for embedding of $W^{1, q}$ with $1 \le q < \infty$.

Comment: that's a nice argument.

Comment: @ user36236. How do you conclude that $\Vert f\Vert_{H^1}^2=\Vert f_+\Vert_{H^1}^2+\Vert f_- \Vert_{H^1}^2$ hold? I have seen this kind of thing also elsewhere but no proof.

Comment: @TaQ: $f_+$ and $f_-$ have disjoint supports.

Comment: @ Pietro Majer. Usually the support is the closure of the set where the function is nonzero. If you have for example the identity $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, then the support of $f_+$ is $[0,+\infty[$ , and that of $f_-$ is $]-\infty,0]$ . Their intersection is $\{0\}$ . So they **do not** have disjoint supports.

Comment: I also have a *feeling* (but not an explicit example) that one can construct an example where ${\rm supp\kern.5mm}f_+\cap{\rm supp\kern.5mm}f_-$ has positive measure.

Comment: @TaQ: By the chain rule for the positive part (which is equivalent to the chain rule for the absolute value and can be proved by approximating the positive part by smooth functions) $\nabla (f_+) = \chi_{f > 0} \nabla f$. In particular $\nabla (f_+) \cdot \nabla (f_-) = 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @ user36236: "... can be proved by approximating the positive part by smooth functions" This suggests me to consider the following. Let $\langle\kern.5mm\varphi_n:n\in\mathbb Z^+\kern.4mm\rangle$ be a $\delta$–sequence and let $\chi$ be the indicator of the set where $f$ is positive. For $\psi$ in $\mathscr D(\Omega)$, then $\int_{\kern.5mm\Omega}(\varphi_n*f_+\cdot\partial_i\psi)=-\int_{\kern.5mm\Omega}(\partial_i(\varphi_n*f_+)\cdot\psi)=-\int_{\kern.5mm\Omega}(\partial_i(\varphi_n*(\chi\cdot f))\cdot\psi)$ , and one should somehow conclude that (cont.)

Comment: $\int_{\kern.5mm\Omega}(\partial_i(\varphi_n*(\chi\cdot f))\cdot\psi)\to\int_{\kern.5mm\Omega}((\chi\cdot\partial_if)\cdot\psi)$ as $n\to+\infty$ . Since $\partial_i\chi$ (considered as a distribution) can be quite "bad", I do not see how this could prove the assertion. However, I have a different idea which possibly could provide a rigorous proof of the assertion that a (weak partial) derivative of $f_+$ is $\chi\cdot(\partial_if)$ although I have not yet checked the details.

Comment: @TaQ: The idea of the approximation is to take $f_n = \sqrt{\vert f \vert^2 + 1/n^2}$, apply the change rule and pass to the limit.

Answer (score 2):

For bounded domains it follows from the Rellich-Kondrashov compactness theorem $H^1\subset\subset L^p$.

If you denote by 
$$
S = \inf \frac{\|u\|{H^1}}{\|u\|_{L^p}}
$$

and take a sequence $\{u_n\}$ such that $\|u_n\|_{H^1}\to S$ and $\|u_n\|_{L^p} = 1$

then there exists a subsequence $\{u_{n_k}\}$ and a function $u$ such that $u_{n_k}\rightharpoonup u$ weakly in $H^1$ and so

$$
\|u\|_{H^1}\le \liminf \|u_{n_k}\|_{H^1} = S
$$

Now, you apply R-K Theorem to conclude that $u_{n_k}\to u$ strongly in $L^p$ and so $\|u\|_{L^p}=1$.

By the maximum principle, as you said, it follows that the function $u$ must be positive inside the domain.